# Are these model validations overkill if schema is already restrictive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a restrictive schema (i.e. the schema already has null restrictions and maximum length etc). Would putting all of them in the model also overkill and counterproductive?...

```
  validates :CouponID,      :presence => true,
                            :numericality => true

  validates :MerchantName,  :presence => true,
                            :length => { :maximum => 100 }

  validates :MerchantID,    :presence => true,
                            :numericality => true

  validates :Network,       :length => { :maximum => 20 }

  validates :Label,         :presence => true

  validates :CouponCode,    :length => { :maximum => 100 }

  validates :EndDate,       :presence => true

  validates :Link,          :presence => true

  validates :Status,        :presence => true,
                            :length => { :maximum => 45 }

  validates :Country,       :length => { :maximum => 100 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not an overkill. Putting these into validators your model would allow Rails to catch them before inserting them into the database. It's also good design and practice.

If you omitted these, you would get MySQL errors thrown instead.

For example. Let's say I have a `Comment` model which contains an attribute string called `body` which can not be nil in my table.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

If I tried:

`comment = Comment.create(body: nil)`

I would get the following exception.

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'body' cannot be null:`

This is bad. The natural flow of your application would break.

But, if I put the validators in my model like so

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

and tried the following:

`comment = Comment.create(body: nil)`

I would not get an exception thrown but the `errors` array for my variable to tell me what went wrong.

```
comment.errors.full_messages
=> ["Body can't be blank"]
```

It's good practice to put validators in your models and allows for good design.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I didn't realize the error handling part. That clears it all up.

Comment: I mostly agree with your answer, but there is one relevant point missing: you "repeat" here something in setting validations and adding the constraints to your database tables. How about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) of the pragmatic programmer? I don't have an answer, but it is a relevant question in my opinion ...

Comment: I see your point. I don't consider it going against DRY since it's not actually code. What if a requirement was to change platforms but keep the database and its data. With DB constraints, you're not relying on the application tier for data integrity. This is all opinion and I am open to discuss it. :) I do see your point though.